# Display nested relationships on a single view

Tags: 8, views

**Context**

I have three custom node types (Batch, Item, Order) that I use to track orders (I don't need the power of full-blown Commerce). These are linked through the following entity reference fields:

Batch->Item through field_items on Batch

Order->Item through field_items on Order

I have a table view set up which shows Items by Batch.

**The Question**

Is there a way I can display, on the same view, the Order name (if any) that each Item is allocated to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I've largely solved this one as follows:

- The View is set to a table showing content of type Batch
- I've added two relationships. The first is to items referenced by the content which are of type = Item (and which does not use any relationship). The second is to items having a reference to the content, are of type Order, and use the first relationship
- I've then added fields from all three content types (using the appropriate relationships) to create the flat table I'm looking for.